# Python: for loop iteration accumulate values in string variable

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Say I have a for loop that iterates through the characters in a string one by one.

Ex:

```
string_x = "abc"
 for i in range (0, len(string_x))
     data = str(string_x[i])
     print(data)
```

The output gives me a, b, c one by one.

Now I want to group this back into a different string after I scramble it character by character. I already figured out how to scramble it, but I can't just append it back to a string inside the loop because it overrides the string value each iteration and only ends up with one character such as 'b'.
I want the for loop to create a new string named string_y that can incrementally have new characters appended to it without overriding the whole string every loop iteration.
Any ideas?

Comment: += instead of = (and initialize data to "").

Comment: Your question is not much clear, can you gives the excepted outputs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
string_x = "abc"
data = ""
for i in range (0, len(string_x)):
    data += str(string_x[i])
print(data)
```

output

```
abc
```

you can use `+=` or `data = data + str(string_x[i])`

Comment: I knew it was simple. Thanks. I've been up too long.

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty clear question, but I'll give it a try.

Since you didn't mention it, I'll just presume that you got something like a scrambled list like `scrambled_list = ['c', 'a', 'b']`.

I guess you're asking for something like `''.join(scrambled_list)`, which will give you `'cab'`.

```
scrambled_list = ['c', 'a', 'b']
sep = ''
output = sep.join(scrambled_list)

print(output)
'cab'
```

the join() method of string returns a string concatenate by the seperater, so

`'-'.join(scrambled_list)` will gives you `'c-a-b'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `+=` (as suggested by [xzoert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362531/python-for-loop-iteration-accumulate-values-in-string-variable/44362691#comment75726570_44362531) in his comment)

```
string_x = 'abc'
string_y = ''  # init to empty string
for c in string_x:
    string_y += c  # add a character to string_y
print string_y
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add letter b to an existing string_y suppose, you'll have to concatenate it to the existing string_y like

```
string_y = string_y + 'b'
```

or in the above loop, it would be

```
string_x = "abc"
string_y = ""
 for i in range (0, len(string_x))
     data = str(string_x[i])
     print(data)
     string_y = string_y + data
```

Since strings are immutable data types in Python, concatenating two strings together actually creates a third string which is the combination of the previous two. So it's more efficient to add the letters to a list and combine it into a string.

```
string_x = "abc"
stringlist = []
 for i in range (0, len(string_x))
     data = str(string_x[i])
     print(data)
     stringlist.append(data)
string_y = "".join(stringlist)
```